# Increment or decrement the value of an array index in C

Tags: c, arrays, decrement

I have code that looks like the following:

```
int some_array[8];
some_array[7] = an_integer;
if ( 550 < some_value ) {
  some_array[7]--;
  log("Lowered the value");
}
```

I expect that should I see the string "Lowered the value" in my logs, I should know the code is being executed. However, I am seeing the logged string but the value does not change. Is there and something I am missing in C with `some_array[7]--`?

Comment: why do you think that you `some_value` greater then 550? where is it assigned?

Comment: Does this compile... likes like you have two variables with the same name to me.

Comment: @IlyaBursov He's seeing the `log("Lowered the value");` that's in the same `if` statement.

Comment: @IlyaBursov It's not always greater then 550. However, in cases that it is I am getting log messages saying the block was executed.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel You may want to drop the `int` from the second line and try running it again...

Comment: @ToothlessRebel hm, so when some_value>550 you get log message, what is wrong then?

Comment: @nhgrif Yeah, I copied and pasted it incorrectly here.

Comment: Try `(some_array[7])--;` or `some_array[7] -= 1;`

Comment: @Hogan It compiles and I get the log message.

Comment: @IlyaBursov some_array[7] isn't changed.

Comment: Voting to close: can't reproduce results. (Dropping `int` in front of `some_array[7] = an_integer;`) works fine for me.

Comment: @Kninnug In that case, I'm undeleting my answer.  Original question asker lead us to believe it was a copy&paste error.

Comment: @nhgrif Yeah, fair enough, it's weird though. It shouldn't even compile due to a double declaration, and then an integer is also an invalid initializer for an array, so it won't compile when dropping `int some_array[8];` resolving the double declaration... What compiler are you using, @ToothlessRebel?

Comment: @Kninnug gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)

Comment: Then, if the code is exactly as posted, the code must work as intended: if `550 < some_value` `some_array[7]` will have its value decremented by one and a message "Lowered the value" will be logged". Is there maybe some other code that modifies `some_array`?

Comment: After verifying the correctness of `some_array[7]--;` and following the logic of some of your advises I have found that the values are being modified elsewhere and preventing me from seeing the changes as written here. That makes an answer difficult, I am unsure of the StackOverflow etiquette for this. Recommend voting for deletion?

Comment: @ToothlessRebel You can just delete the question.  It's your own question.

Comment: @nhgrif Not if has answers

Answer (score 0):

```
int some_array[8];
int some_array[7] = an_integer;  //This is the problem line.
if ( 550 < some_value ) {
   some_array[7]--;
   log("Lowered the value");
}
```

This code isn't doing what you think it's doing.

You don't have `some_array` with 8 indexes.  You have `some_array` with 7 indexes, and `some_array[7]` is out of the bounds of what `some_array[]` actually holds (but `C` doesn't throw exceptions for this).  Try this:

```
int some_array[8];
some_array[7] = an_integer;
if ( 550 < some_value ) {
   some_array[7]--;
   log("Lowered the value");
}
```

Comment: I can't even compile it with the double declaration (GCC-4.8.1).

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
int some_array[8];
int some_array[7] = an_integer;

if ( 550 < some_value ) {
  some_array[7] = some_array[7]--;
  log("Lowered the value");
}
```

Comment: `int some_array[7] = an_integer;` is highly problematic.

Comment: `some_array[7] = some_array[7]--;` is *undefined behaviour*: you're modifying the value of `some_array[7]` twice in the same sequence point. (Try compiling it with `gcc -Wall` it will warn)